# PowerBI remote certificate is invalid error

Tags: heroku, powerbi

I have a postgres database on Heroku.
I need to connect to this database on PowerBI using DirectQuery option.

Whenever I try this, I'm getting the following error:

```
an error happened while reading data provider: remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

I have also installed SSL certificates on my Heroku app. Please help me connect my database to PowerBI via DirectQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It is finally possible to use the PostgreSQL connector directly from PowerBI, thanks to heroku beta deployment on enhanced certificates.

You need following commands :

```
heroku plugins:install data
heroku data:enhanced-certificates:enable DATABASE_URL -a example-app
```

It takes 15 minutes to be enable, and creates a new host address for your DB.

More info : https://help.heroku.com/3DELT3RK/why-can-t-my-third-party-utility-connect-to-heroku-postgres-with-ssl

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-enhanced-certificates